# Is it possible to send HTTP response using GZIP and byte ranges at the same time?

Tags: http, range, gzip

Request:

```
...
Content-Range: bytes 27482871-41601067/41601068
...
```

I have tried to read the bytes from file and later to GZIP. The response looks like this:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);

...
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 21:44:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=1800
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename*=utf-8''Marq_Aurel_Rayman_Rave_-_Intdo_The_Blue_%28Max_R_remix%29.wav
ETag: Marq_Aurel_Rayman_Rave_-_Intdo_The_Blue_%28Max_R_remix%29.wav-41601068-1403655006000
Cache-Control: private,max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:10:06 GMT
Content-Range: bytes 27482871-41601067/41601068
Content-Encoding: gzip
...
```

And the download fails if I pause and resume it. Maybe I should never use GZIP in range response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to request gzipped content over a range, but only with `Transfer-Encoding`, and *not* with `Content-Encoding`.

`Content-Encoding` won't work if you're asking for a range of bytes: it implies the server encodes the entire document, and if the entire content is encoded with gzip and you only request a range of it you won't know enough to unzip it. (You can't decompress a partial gzip, or at least not without its start.)

Rather than using range to serve a chunk of the entire compressed document, you could use `Transfer-Encoding` instead. This'll serve you the range you want, and compress that range. Much better!

Unintuitively, whilst you request `Content-Encoding` with an `Accept-Encoding` header, you request `Transfer-Encoding` with a `TE` header.

However, this is where things get sticky: few web-servers support it. If you're pulling content from CloudFlare you'll see that they don't, for instance.

Here's [a discussion from the nginx mailing-list](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,209738,210053#msg-210053) where they discuss exactly this problem, and here's [another on making it work in HTTP/2](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/httpbisa/current/msg18483.html).

Comment: Will the bytes range be of the original uncompressed payload or of the compressed one? I guess it must be the former? I think so because as I understood each chunk is compressed individually.

Comment: @Khoi yes, that's right! You're specifying a range in terms of the content stored on the server. There's no `Content-Encoding` here!

Comment: I found out later that you can't send `TE` header in Chrome neither could it parse `Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked` response. Feels like we're years away from seeing this in the browser.

Comment: I believe the answer is incorrect, as explained on [nginx forum here](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,209738,210053#msg-210053). There's also [this source on w3 standard mailing lists](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2014JanMar/1179.html) that says you can request range on a content-encoded payload.

Comment: Surely those links support the answer: "Content-Encoding: gzip is actually a misnomer because in most cases it is actually used as a transfer encoding", "range requests + gzip compression provide a huge performance gain, but is impossible (in a compliant manner) without using gzip transfer encoding for the reasons mentioned", etc. There's a difference between what you can legally request as per RFC and many servers support!